# How do I delete an entire Array by choosing the product from the combobox?

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2010, combobox

This is my current code for an aquarium inventory update sales thingy. I haven't coded anything for the delete button cause I don't know how to do it.

```
    namespace Project_Aquarium
    {
public partial class Form1 : Form
{

    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }


    string[] product = new string[10];
    float[] retailprice = new float[10];
    float[] costprice = new float[10];
    int[] quantity = new int[10];
    int[] totalSold = new int[10];


    private void btnCheck_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < product.Length; i++)
        {
            if (cbProduct.SelectedIndex.Equals(i))
            {
                lblRetail.Text = retailprice[i].ToString();
                lblCost.Text = costprice[i].ToString();
                lblInStock.Text = quantity[i].ToString();
                lblSold.Text = totalSold[i].ToString();
            }
        }
    }

    private void btnCheckClear_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        lblRetail.Text = "";
        lblCost.Text = "";
        lblInStock.Text = "";
        lblSold.Text = "";
    }

    private void btnAdd_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

        if (cbProduct.Items.Count < 10)
        {
            string name = txtProductAdd.Text;
            float cost_price, retail_price;
            int totalQty;
            string searchProduct = txtProductAdd.Text;

            if (float.TryParse(txtRetailAdd.Text, out retail_price) == false)
            {
                MessageBox.Show("Please Enter Retail Price.");
                txtRetailAdd.Clear();
                txtRetailAdd.Focus();
            }
            else if (float.TryParse(txtCostAdd.Text, out cost_price) == false)
            {
                MessageBox.Show("Please Enter Cost Price");
                txtCostAdd.Clear();
                txtCostAdd.Focus();
            }


            else if (int.TryParse(txtQuantityAdd.Text, out totalQty) == false)
            {
                MessageBox.Show("Please Enter Quantity of Product.");
                txtQuantityAdd.Clear();
                txtQuantityAdd.Focus();
            }

            else

                for (int i = 0; i < product.Length; i++)
                {
                    if (searchProduct == product[i])
                    {
                        MessageBox.Show("Store Already Has This Product.");
                        break;
                    }
                    else if (product[i] == null && searchProduct != product[i])
                    {
                        product[i] = name;
                        retailprice[i] = retail_price;
                        costprice[i] = cost_price;
                        quantity[i] = totalQty;
                        MessageBox.Show(txtProductAdd.Text
                            + " was added. "
                            + "Quantity is: "
                            + txtQuantityAdd.Text);
                        break;
                    }
                }

            cbProduct.Items.Add(name);
            cbProductDelete.Items.Add(name);
            cbProductEdit.Items.Add(name);
            cbProductSold.Items.Add(name);
        }
        else
        {
            MessageBox.Show("Storage space has exceeded.");

        }
    }


    private void btnClear_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        txtProductAdd.Text = "";
        txtCostAdd.Clear();
        txtRetailAdd.Clear();
        txtQuantityAdd.Clear();

        txtProductAdd.Focus();
    }


    private void btnSold_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

        string searchFish = cbProductSold.Text;
        int foundIndex = -1;
        int sold = 0;

        if (cbProductSold.SelectedItem == null)
        {
            MessageBox.Show("Please Select A Product.");
        }

        else if (txtQuantitySEdit.Text == "")
        {
            MessageBox.Show("Please enter a value for quantity.");
            txtQuantitySEdit.Focus();
        }

        else if (int.TryParse(txtQuantitySEdit.Text, out sold) == false)
        {
            MessageBox.Show("Please enter a numeric value for quantity.");
            txtQuantitySEdit.Focus();
        }

        else
        {
            for (int i = 0; i < product.Length; i++)
            {
                if (searchFish == product[i])
                {
                    foundIndex = i;
                    break;
                }
            }
        }
        if (quantity[foundIndex] < sold)
        {
            MessageBox.Show("There is not enough fish to be sold. Current product chosen quantity is: "
                + quantity[foundIndex]);
        }
        else if (foundIndex != -1)
        {
            totalSold[foundIndex] = totalSold[foundIndex] + sold;

            quantity[foundIndex] = quantity[foundIndex] - sold;

            lblNettPrice.Text = costprice[foundIndex].ToString("");
            lblQuantityChosen.Text = sold.ToString("");
            lblTotalPrice.Text = CalculateTotalPrice(sold, costprice[foundIndex]).ToString("C");

        }
    }

    private float CalculateTotalPrice(int sold, float costprice)
    {
        float nettPrice;
        nettPrice = sold * costprice;
        return nettPrice;
    }



    private void btnSave_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        string foundProduct = txtProductEdit.Text;
        string editName = txtProductEdit.Text;
        float editCost, editRetail;
        int editQty;
        int editSold;

        editName = txtProductEdit.Text;
        editRetail = float.Parse(txtRetailEdit.Text);
        editCost = float.Parse(txtCostEdit.Text);
        editQty = int.Parse(txtQuantityEdit.Text);
        editSold = int.Parse(txtSoldEdit.Text);

        for (int i = 0; i < product.Length; i++)
        {

            product[i] = editName;
            retailprice[i] = editRetail;
            costprice[i] = editCost;
            quantity[i] = editQty;
            totalSold[i] = editSold;
            MessageBox.Show(product[i]
                + " Has Been Updated.");
            break;
        }
    }




    private void btnDelete_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

    }

    private void btnSelectEditProduct_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    { 
        for (int i = 0; i < product.Length; i++)
        {
            if (cbProductEdit.SelectedIndex.Equals(i))
            {

                txtProductEdit.Text = product[i].ToString();
                txtRetailEdit.Text = retailprice[i].ToString();
                txtCostEdit.Text = costprice[i].ToString();
                txtQuantityEdit.Text = quantity[i].ToString();
                txtSoldEdit.Text = totalSold[i].ToString();

            }

        }

    }

}
   }
```

So, in my GUI for the "delete product", has a combobox (cbProductDelete) and a button to click delete. Yeah. This delete product is supposed to delete everything in the Array of the product, so that the User can add in a different Array, cause the max is 10 Arrays. Umm. Is it even possible? P.s, please tell me if I'm not being clear with my question..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This may/maynot directly answer your question. but I hope I'll guide you in right direction.

Do in in a "object oriented" way. Introduce a class which holds related groups of properties. Let's say `Product`

```
public class Product
{
    public string ProductName{ get; set; }
    public float RetailPrice{ get; set; }
    public float CostPrice{ get; set; }
    public int Quantity{ get; set; }
    public int TotalSold{ get; set; }
}
```

Then, use `List<Product>` not simply an `Array` arrays are fixed in size. When you want to add/remove elements you have to use `Collections`.

```
private List<Products> myProducts = new List<Products>();
```

To add elements to the list, you need to create an instance of `Product` then add.

```
Product product = new Product{ ProductName = "Something", RetailPrice = 10.26f,...};
myProducts.Add(product);
```

To remove an element use `Remove` or `RemoveAt` method.

```
foreach(var product in myProducts)
{
    if(product.ProductName == "ProductToRemove")
    {
        myProducts.Remove(product);
        break;//Must else you'll get an exception
    }
}
```

I hope you can solve your problem in your own with this info.

Comment: Umm, by using this code, will my Arrays be fixed? Cause it's not supposed to be fixed. And, what does 
`public class Product
{
    public string ProductName{ get; set; }
    public float RetailPrice{ get; set; }
    public float CostPrice{ get; set; }
    public int Quantity{ get; set; }
    public int TotalSold{ get; set; }
}
`
the ` {get; set;}` do? 

and the `foreach( var product in myProducts) `
what does "var" stand for?

Comment: Sorry i don't really get your codes cause i haven't learnt this yet. Ahaha. :/

Comment: Oh.. I think you need a beginner tutorial.. Get a book and that will help. That is a class and `foreach(var product in myProducts)` is just looping through all products. [var](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb383973.aspx) is a keyword, which is called implicitly typed local variables. Pls keep reading on tutorials.